# Mongo DB Search and sort not working - collection.find(...).sort is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

I have a use case to search for a particular string on one field and return the results in sorted order based on another field.
The below is the function I'm using in Node.js and the error being thrown.

```
router.get("/getappts/:username", function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.params.username)
  collection.find({ username: req.params.username }).sort( {date : 1} ), function (err, appointments) {
    if (err) throw err;
    
    console.log(appointments)
    res.json(appointments);
  } 
})
```

Error - collection.find(...).sort is not a function.

Not sure how to model the query.

But the below query on Mongo Compass seems to work fine -

[image]

Comment: Please show us how you define the collection

Comment: This is my collection -  
 {  "tutor": "Victor Fredrick",
"username" :  "Nikesh Manjunath",
"date" : 2022-04-29T20:25:00.000+00:00 }

Answer (score 0):

might be where your callback is, I would suggest using promises instead

```js
router.get("/getappts/:username", async function (req, res) {
  try {
    console.log(req.params.username)
    const appointments = await collection.find({ username: req.params.username }).sort({ date : 1 })
    
    console.log(appointments)
    res.json(appointments);
  } catch (err) {
    throw err;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I really appreciate it. I did try your suggestion, yet it throws the error "TypeError: collection.find(...).sort is not a function".